# How to split an HTTP Request Body in two parts?

Tags: c#, rest, dotnet-httpclient, multipart

I'm fairly new to use HTTPClient and sending REST requests to APIs, I'm currently practicing multipart upload using this Google Drive API endpoint:

POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart

There's an instruction that states there to split the request body into two parts, I tried to recreate this but was unable to do so.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads#multipart

Here's my current code:

```cs
async void UploadFile(StorageFile fileName)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        // Opens files and convert it to stream
        var resultStream = await fileName.OpenReadAsync();
        var fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(resultStream.AsStream());

        // Create file MetaData
        var fileMetaData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                            new { name = fileName.Name,  mimetype = fileName.ContentType });

        // Create POST request
        var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uploadFileEndpoint);
        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(tokenType, accessToken);
        // Add request body
        requestMessage.Content = new StringContent(fileMetaData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        requestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/related");

        var response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        output(responseString);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Don't use `StringContent`, you probably want https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.multipartformdatacontent?view=net-7.0

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Hi, can you provide an example? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation on [Perform a multipart upload (HTTP tab)](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads#http_1), you need the [`MultipartFormDataContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.multipartformdatacontent?view=net-7.0) as suggested by @Jeremy.

There are a few things needed to perform/migrate:

1. Add `AuthenticationHeaderValue` into `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization`.
2. Create a `StreamContent` instance, `fileStreamContent` *(which you have done)* and specify its `Headers.ContentType`.
3. Create a `StringContent` instance, `stringContent` *(which you have done)*.
4. Append both `StreamContent` and `StringContent` into the `MultipartFormDataContent` instance, `formData`.
5. Specify the `formData`'s `Headers.ContentType` as requested in API docs.
6. Post the `formData` with `await client.PostAsync(/* API Url */, formData);`

```cs
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(tokenType, accessToken);

    // Opens files and convert it to stream
    var resultStream = await fileName.OpenReadAsync();
    var fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(resultStream.AsStream());
                
    fileStreamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(fileName.ContentType);

    // Create file MetaData
    var fileMetaData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { name = fileName.Name, mimetype = fileName.ContentType });
    var stringContent = new StringContent(fileMetaData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

   // Create POST request
   MultipartFormDataContent formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();
   formData.Add(stringContent, "metadata");
   formData.Add(fileStreamContent, "media");

   formData.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/related");

   var response = await client.PostAsync(uploadFileEndpoint, formData);
   string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: Didn't test the code, based on the API docs, the concept should be as above.

Comment: This worked! I removed the line    formData.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/related"); though since the headers were automatically generated when adding the formdata. :D Thanks alot <3

Comment: @MartinKing, you're welcome. Glad to see it helps.